# How to fix package R does not exist setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) and it consequences?

Tags: java, android

At first the error message was :

> error: package R does not exist setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

then I read a lot of answers in the StackOverflow about this problem so I tried to check the package name in the MainActivity and also the manifest file and then imported mypackage.R, then the problem message becomes like that:

```
    Creating myapp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
C:\Users\m0unta\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:960: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\m0unta\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:971: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\m0unta\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:314: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.x509.X500Name
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.writeSignatureBlock(SignedJarBuilder.java:384)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.close(SignedJarBuilder.java:273)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.sealApk(ApkBuilder.java:795)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:371)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Note: I am using Netbeans, and not Android Studio (maybe this is the problem, I don't know )

Comment: This problem generally occurs when one of your resource XMLs have an error. See if there is an error in your XMLs

Answer (score 4):

R.java  is generated when building your app.  The first thing to do to try to solve this error is to clean and rebuild your project.  If you still get the same error,  then check all XML files. Errors in AndroidManifest.xml and any layout or other XML resource files will stop generation of R.java.

I strongly suggest that you switch to Android Studio since it is the officially supported IDE.

Comment: I have only two Xml files because i have just created the project
activity_main  :

Comment: @Mountassir A new project has more than two XML files. Android Studio generates several in the subfolders of `res`. Have you manually modified any of these or AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: no i didn't modify any file + i checked the files i have only 3 files ( the mainfest + activity_main + Strings ) they doesn't contain any errors @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly like @Code-Apprentice said: I had made a new project by copying files from old project.

Tried to run: `Package R does not exist`.

I did `Clean` and `Rebuild`, twice; still had the error.

I swear to you that I checked every `xml` file - `AndroidManifest, ic_launcher, activity_main, colors, dimens, strings` - but saw no problem, so I ran.

Same error, of course; I'd changed nothing. Considered exiting and restarting Studio. Nah. As Rocky said to Bullwinkle who was about to try to pull a rabbit from a hat, "That trick never works." (But sometimes it does.)

So my brain finally fired up an idea: I did a **global project search** for the old `package` name and found it in 3 places, one of which I could change: in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I had changed one, but not the other occurrence of the old `package` name.

P.S.
I had wondered why I was getting a "can't find" sort of message on this line:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

I changed it to `com.dslomer64.volumecontrolssbplus.MainActivity` and no other error occurred at the time, but then I ran and got the "R" error. (I SHOULD have smelled a rat and looked closely right then at the rest of `AndroidManifest`.)

The Moral:  Look closely at all `xml` (especially `AndroidManifest`?) and then look closer and if you still don't see the problem, do a global project search for the old package name, with options "match case" and "whole word".

Answer (score 0):

mention

```
import com.projectdir.subdir.R;
```

in your java file..

it needs proper path to access R

....mine worked after this